# How to create an instance of the internal constructor with parameters using Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I have a different scenario. I need to **create instance of a class which is public but having all its constructors as internal**. The class has no default constructor.

I tried the below ways, but it didn't work.

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ClassName));
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ClassName), nonpublic:true);
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ClassName),true);
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ClassName), new object[]{double,bool});
```

I also tried this, but ended up with System.MissingMethodException.

```
var constructors = typeof(ClassName).GetConstructors();
foreach(var ctor in constructors)
    ctor.Invoke(new object[] {double, bool});
```

I **am not able to use BindingFlags in Xamrarin**. I am stuck, does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: The author of the class made the decision that instances of the class should not be created outside of its assembly. You are trying to hack that decision. Do you really need to create an instance? Are you just misunderstanding its use? Can the code be changed to make the constructor public? Using reflection here should be a last resort.

Comment: Well I tried other ways and could not find any of it working. Hence as a last option decided to go for reflection. It would be helpful if you I am pointed to a solution for this.

Comment: Is the class that you trying to create the instance of it created by you? If so there might be other solutions to create an instance without reflection.

Comment: No it is not. It is an already existing class in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: You're probably using PCL project which doesn't have all reflection methods you need. You could convert your project to shared project type and use Invoke with BindingFlags, etc.

Comment: Hi Daniel,Thanks for the idea. But I have found my own solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. Here is what I did.

```
ConstructorInfo info = typeof(ClassName).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors.First();
ClassName e = info.Invoke(new object[] { parameters }) as ClassName;
```

I hope this might help someone. Cheers:)